# ffmpeg bitrate/quality selection

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm attempting to copy videos from a site. They are stored in 6 different resolutions, as an hls stream format. When I use the command `ffmpeg -i http://c.brightcove.com/services/mobile/streaming/index/master.m3u8?videoId=5506754630001 -c copy output.ts` I get the highest quality (1280x720). However, when I `wget` the .m3u8 I can see there are other qualities but am having trouble with how to copy those quality (i.e. 640x380). the original link is http://www.sportsnet.ca/hockey/nhl/analyzing-five-potential-trade-destinations-matt-duchene/.

I'm hoping someone can help me out with this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's of any help but

```
ffmpeg -i http(s)//link/to/input.m3u8 -map m:variant_bitrate:BITRATE -c copy output.ts
```

is a valid approach for selection of the quality.

The `variant_bitrate` meta tag is documented here: [FFmpeg Formats Documentation#applehttp](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#applehttp).

The stream specifiers that can be used via `-map` option are documented here:
[ffmpeg Documentation#5.1 Stream specifiers](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-specifiers-1)

This means you need to know the `BITRATE` of the master, which can be a bit more complicated...

If it's still of interest, I can get back with a python 3.6 script that would require an external module...

or you have to manually check which bitrate you need
(in browser or with `ffprobe-i http(s)//link/to/input.m3u8` )

If anyone knows more about this it would be nice to know when this `variant_bitrate` meta tag was implemeted as I'm quite sure that this wasn't always possible...

Comment: This is nice, thanks. Do you know if I can use `-map m:variant_bitrate:BITRATE` somehow in ffplay (to select quality to play)? If I use it like that I get "Failed to set value 'm:variant_bitrate:12345' for option 'map': Option not found"